# Potential False Positive warning in VS? "DF0108: Activity function named '{myfunction}' doesn't have an input"

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I have a durable function with an activity trigger that takes one enumerated value as an input.

Here is the call to that activity trigger from within the orchestrator.

```cs
await context.CallActivityAsync("NotifySolutionStatus", SolutionStatus.Status.Completed);
```

Here is the activity trigger signature:

```cs
[FunctionName("NotifySolutionStatus")]
public static async Task NotifySolutionStatus(
   [ActivityTrigger] SolutionStatus.Status status,
   [SignalR(HubName = "broadcast")] IAsyncCollector<SignalRMessage> signalRMessages,
   ILogger log)
```

Visual Studio 2019 is returning the warning:

> Activity function named 'NotifySolutionStatus' doesn't have an input.
> Pass null for the input parameter

What's really odd to me is that the activity trigger works just fine, and the input value is successfully passed. Also, this warning is not being thrown for any other calls to other activity triggers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having discovered this recently, the solution was to remove any namespacing from the parameter type.

so this trips up the analyzer

```
public async Task<ServiceResult<Models.Folder.Item>> Run(
        [ActivityTrigger] Models.Folder.Item item)
    {
        //code
    }
```

Refactor to

```
public async Task<ServiceResult<Models.Folder.Item>> Run(
        [ActivityTrigger] Item item)
    {
        //code
    }
```

and the analyzer is satisfied. In my specific case, I had to alias the Type to get around the issue due to a namespace collision.

Answer (score 2):

I just was fighting against the same behaviour named **Error DF0108: Activity function** and found an interesting solution to my current situation.

It seems that the compiler checks whether the input you put in is used within the function, but the compiler only investigates the first line of the function code. This compile behaviour is reproducible by making the method call `blabla.GetInput<ResultObject>()`  not to be the first line of code in your funtion.

**Compiles without problems**

```
public async Task<Response> SendSomethingAsync([ActivityTrigger] IDurableActivityContext context)
        {
            var input = context.GetInput<Input>();
            var correlationId = context.InstanceId;

            // ...
        }
```

**Error DF0108: Activity function**

```
public async Task<Response> SendSomethingAsync([ActivityTrigger] IDurableActivityContext context)
        {
            var correlationId = context.InstanceId;
            var input = context.GetInput<Input>();
            
            // ...
        }
```

Comment: Damn @Sebastian Parkitny, you were absolutely right! I was getting these build warnings it seems, because I surrounded my Activity run method code in
`using (log.BeginScope()) { }`. Moving this below the `context.GetInput<>()` solved the problem. 

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Below code seems no problem:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.SignalRService;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp53
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        public enum Status
        {
            Spring=0,
            Summer=1,
            Autumn=2,
            Winter=3
        }
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<List<string>> RunOrchestrator(
            [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
        {
            var outputs = new List<string>();

            outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("Function1_Hello", Function1.Status.Spring));
            outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("Function1_Hello", Function1.Status.Summer));
            outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("Function1_Hello", Function1.Status.Autumn));

            return outputs;
        }

        [FunctionName("Function1_Hello")]
        public static string SayHello([ActivityTrigger] Function1.Status name, [SignalR(HubName = "chat")] IAsyncCollector<SignalRMessage> signalRMessages, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"Saying hello to {name}.");
            return $"Hello {name}!";
        }

        [FunctionName("Function1_HttpStart")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> HttpStart(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestMessage req,
            [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter,
            ILogger log)
        {
            // Function input comes from the request content.
            string instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync("Function1", null);

            log.LogInformation($"Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.");

            return starter.CreateCheckStatusResponse(req, instanceId);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the output:

[image]

On errors or warnings:

[image]

Maybe you can show your code?